# How to get images to resize in chrome, IE and safari

Tags: jquery, css, image, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I am developing a website which uses the jquery tabs api. For each tab I have a picture which I want to resize when the size of the browser is changed.

This is an example of one of the tabs

```
<li style='width:15%'>
  <a href="/fu...">
   <img src="/Funde..." alt="BreakOut" class="breakoutFundviewImage">
  </a>
</li>
```

I have it working fine in firefox and IE by using simple CSS

```
.breakoutFundviewImage
{
    height:30px;    
    width: 100%;    
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work in chrome, safari. The images are simply displayed at full size and therefore only half of the image is seen in the tab.

Does anyone know the correct way of doing this? Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set a height on the images or you'll break the aspect ratio. You code is correct so if they aren't resizing then it's because the parent tags are wider than you think they are. You probably have some overflow:hidden going on where the inner elements are being cropped instead of resized.

Comment: Ok thanks for that. I have the images in the containers as listed in example above. Can you see any issue with that setup?

Comment: I suspect jQuery tabs requires the use of an overflow:hidden container (like most slideshows) so it will be tricky for you to get it to scale. You may have to rethink your approach completely.